# MATLAB fmincon() not satisfying constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a nonlinear function to minimize, that satisfies a linear inequality constraint and a non-negativity constraint.  I use `fmincon` setting the lower bound to `0` for this.

It seems that the answer I get does not satisfy `x >= 0`, although the linear inequality constraint is satisfied. I am not sure if the function I am trying to minimize is convex (It may have local minima), but I do not think this should affect anything.

FYI here is the syntax I am using:

```
h = fmincon(@(x)constraint_test(x,s,Cov), A,b, [],[], 0,[])
```

`constraint_test` is the function to be minimized, all other variables (`s,Cov,A,b`) are known.

Comment: Okay, I changed code so that the non-negativity constraint is absorbed into the linear inequality constraint. I am now getting an answer that is feasible, but I am sure that is not the right answer.Also, I am very curious to know why it wasn't working before

Comment: What are `constraint_test`, `s`, `Cov`, `A` and `b`? Without that information it will be very hard to answer your question.

Comment: -1: see my answer. I'm downvoting because a simple `help fmincon` or `doc fmincon` would have given you a wealth of information on how to analyze this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `fmincon` has a bunch of additional outputs

```
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA] = fmincon(...)
```

of which `EXITFLAG` and `OUTPUT` provide all sorts of information on how the optimization terminated. Additionally, you can pass in an option:

```
options = optimset('display', 'iter-detailed');

h = fmincon(..., options);
```

which will show you exactly what `fmincon` is deciding and doing on each iteration.

It sounds like it just wasn't able to find any feasible solution, which is something that will definitely show up when you analyze these outputs.